# how can i launch the android tool?

Tags: android, android-emulator

I need to do somethings that must be done from the command prompt of the android tool.

but every one says it's in the platform tools folder in the sdk path but which file is it?

that might help:

the contents of platform tools folder:

```
aapt.exe
adb.exe
aidl.exe
dexdump.exe
dx.bat
fastboot.exe
llvm-rs-cc.exe
source.properties
AdbWinApi.dll
AdbWinUsbApi.dll
```

Comment: the command promot that i can make AVDs from it and launch projects on them.

Comment: __AVD Manager.exe__ ? mine is in the root of the sdk path?

Comment: no not the gui i mean the command one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you mean android Adb command lin tool if so see this [link](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-use-android-adb-command-line-tool/)

if you want to manage emulator from command line see these three link it will help you a lot

[Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html#starting)

[Using the Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html)

[Android Emulator on Linux](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/10/create-android-virtual-device-avd-in.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is an `android` command, but it's not an executable - run the `android.bat` in the tools directory, and you should be able to make the changes you need.  If you add the tools directory to your system path, you'll be able to run `android` from any directory when using the command line.